# Simplification of multiplication of sparse matrices $B(A A^T)A$

Tags: matrices, sparse-matrices

I have large very sparse $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, (roughly $10^5 \times 10^3$ with ~99% sparsity).

I need to compute $\mathbf{B (A A^\text{T})^{-1}A}$, where $\mathbf{B}$ is a $p \times m$ matrix ($ p \approx 10^3)$ with ~66% sparsity.

Computing each operation in turn, even using algorithms for sparse matrices, is very expensive mainly due to solving the inverse.

Are there any identities or trickery for sparse-matrices which can speed up or simplify the problem?

Comment: Do you really need that matrix in a way where you store every entry in memory or does it suffice to compute its action on vectors later on in your code?